# Proof of Fixed Point Theorem in Compact Spaces

Tags: general-topology, continuity, solution-verification, fixed-point-theorems

[image: TH]

This was a problem for my past paper, here is my attempt to solve it. I know there is an easier solution, but I want to verify if my solution is correct.

**Proof.** Suppose we can find a bound $1> \delta > 0$ such that $$d(f(x),f(y))< \delta d(x,y)$$

Then we are done using the Banach Fixed Point Theorem, since compact metric spaces are complete.

Now assume no such $\delta$ exists. Then we can find sequences $a_i, b_i$ such that $\frac{d(f(a_i), f(b_i)}{d(a_i,b_i)} \rightarrow 1$. Then since a compact metric space is sequentially compact, $a_i$ has a convergent subsequence $a_{i_j} \rightarrow a$ and $b_{i_{j_r}} -> b$. Then we have (by continuity of f) d(f(a), f(b)) = d(a,b). This is a contradiction.

Comment: Isn't there a problem in your proof if $a = b$ ?

Comment: $d(f(x),f(y))< d(x,y)$ is possible only when $x \ne y$. You should edit your question.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1660866/existence-of-fixed-point-given-a-mapping